# GLSL: Sending variable number of textures to sampler2D

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, glsl

I'd like to send a variable array of textures to some shaders, but don't know how to variabilize the number of textures in a uniform sampler2D.

In the example below, for example, I send two textures to the shaders and try to initialize the sampler2D uniform value `texture` with a length of 2. However this yields the following exception:

> THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false
>   gl.getProgramInfoLog invalid shaders  ERROR: 0:125: '' : constant
>   expression required ERROR: 0:125: '' : array size must be a constant
>   integer expression ERROR: 0:134: '[]' : array index out of range

Is it possible to variabilize the number of textures to send to a sampler2D uniform value? I'd be grateful for any insights others can offer on this question!

```js
/**
* Generate a scene object with a background color
**/

function getScene() {
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
  return scene;
}

/**
* Generate the camera to be used in the scene. Camera args:
*   [0] field of view: identifies the portion of the scene
*     visible at any time (in degrees)
*   [1] aspect ratio: identifies the aspect ratio of the
*     scene in width/height
*   [2] near clipping plane: objects closer than the near
*     clipping plane are culled from the scene
*   [3] far clipping plane: objects farther than the far
*     clipping plane are culled from the scene
**/

function getCamera() {
  var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(0, 1, 10);
  return camera;
}

/**
* Generate the renderer to be used in the scene
**/

function getRenderer() {
  // Create the canvas with a renderer
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  // Add support for retina displays
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  // Specify the size of the canvas
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  // Add the canvas to the DOM
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  return renderer;
}

/**
* Generate the controls to be used in the scene
* @param {obj} camera: the three.js camera for the scene
* @param {obj} renderer: the three.js renderer for the scene
**/

function getControls(camera, renderer) {
  var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.zoomSpeed = 0.4;
  controls.panSpeed = 0.4;
  return controls;
}

/**
* Load image
**/

function loadImage() {

  var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

  /*
  Now we need to push some vertices into that geometry to identify the coordinates the geometry should cover
  */

  // Identify the image size
  var imageSize = {width: 10, height: 7.5};

  // Identify the x, y, z coords where the image should be placed
  var coords = {x: -5, y: -3.75, z: 0};

  // Add one vertex for each corner of the image, using the 
  // following order: lower left, lower right, upper right, upper left
  var vertices = new Float32Array([
    coords.x, coords.y, coords.z, // bottom left
    coords.x+imageSize.width, coords.y, coords.z, // bottom right
    coords.x+imageSize.width, coords.y+imageSize.height, coords.z, // upper right
    coords.x, coords.y+imageSize.height, coords.z, // upper left
  ])

  // set the uvs for this box; these identify the following corners:
  // lower-left, lower-right, upper-right, upper-left
  var uvs = new Float32Array([
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
  ])

  // store the texture index of each object to be rendered
  var textureIndices = new Float32Array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]);

  // indices = sequence of index positions in `vertices` to use as vertices
  // we make two triangles but only use 4 distinct vertices in the object
  // the second argument to THREE.BufferAttribute is the number of elements
  // in the first argument per vertex
  geometry.setIndex([0,1,2, 2,3,0])
  geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
  geometry.addAttribute('uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute(uvs, 2));
  geometry.addAttribute('textureIdx', new THREE.BufferAttribute(textureIndices, 1));

  // Create a texture loader so we can load our image file
  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

  // specify the url to the texture
  var catUrl = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/tsne-webgl/assets/cat.jpg';
  var dogUrl = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/tsne-webgl/assets/dog.jpg';

  // get an array of textures
  var textureArr = [loader.load(catUrl), loader.load(dogUrl)];

  // specify custom uniforms and attributes for shaders
  // Uniform types: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Uniforms-types
  var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({  
    uniforms: {

      verticesPerTexture: new Float32Array([4.0]), // store the count of vertices per texture

      texture_num: {
        type: 'i',
        value: textureArr.length,
      },

      cat_texture: {
        type: 't',
        value: loader.load(catUrl),
      },

      dog_texture: {
        type: 't',
        value: loader.load(dogUrl),
      },

      textures: {
        type: 'tv', // type for texture array
        value: textureArr,
      }
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent
  });

  // Combine our image geometry and material into a mesh
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  // Set the position of the image mesh in the x,y,z dimensions
  mesh.position.set(0,0,0)

  // Add the image to the scene
  scene.add(mesh);
}

/**
* Render!
**/

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  controls.update();
};

var scene = getScene();
var camera = getCamera();
var renderer = getRenderer();
var controls = getControls(camera, renderer);
loadImage();

render();
```

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; }
body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js'></script>

<script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertex-shader'>
  /**
  * The vertex shader's main() function must define `gl_Position`,
  * which describes the position of each vertex in the space.
  *
  * To do so, we can use the following variables defined by Three.js:        
  *   
  *   uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix - combines:
  *     model matrix: maps a point's local coordinate space into world space
  *     view matrix: maps world space into camera space
  *
  *   uniform mat4 projectionMatrix - maps camera space into screen space
  *
  *   attribute vec3 position - sets the position of each vertex
  *
  *   attribute vec2 uv - determines the relationship between vertices and textures
  *
  * `uniforms` are constant across all vertices
  *
  * `attributes` can vary from vertex to vertex and are defined as arrays
  *   with length equal to the number of vertices. Each index in the array
  *   is an attribute for the corresponding vertex
  *
  * `varyings` are values passed from the vertex to the fragment shader
  *
  * Specifying attributes that are not passed to the vertex shader will not pevent shader compiling
  **/

  // declare attributes
  attribute float textureIdx;

  // declare uniform vals
  uniform float verticesPerTexture; // store the vertices per texture

  // declare variables to pass to fragment shaders
  varying vec2 vUv; // pass the uv coordinates of each vertex to the frag shader
  varying float vTextureIdx; // pass the texture idx

  void main() {
    vTextureIdx = textureIdx;
    vUv = uv;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
  }
</script>

<script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragment-shader'>
  /**
  * The fragment shader's main() function must define `gl_FragColor`,
  * which describes the pixel color of each pixel on the screen.
  *
  * To do so, we can use uniforms passed into the shader and varyings
  * passed from the vertex shader
  *
  * Attempting to read a varying not generated by the vertex shader will
  * throw a warning but won't prevent shader compiling
  *
  * Each attribute must contain n_vertices * n_components, where n_components
  * is the length of the given datatype (e.g. vec2 n_components = 2;
  * float n_components = 1)
  **/

  precision highp float; // set float precision (optional)

  varying vec2 vUv; // identify the uv values as a varying attribute
  varying float vTextureIdx; // identify the texture indices as a varying attribute

  uniform int texture_num; // identify the number of textures used
  uniform sampler2D cat_texture; // identify the texture as a uniform argument
  uniform sampler2D dog_texture; // identify the texture as a uniform argument
  uniform sampler2D textures[texture_num];

  void main() {
    int textureIndex = int(floor(vTextureIdx));
    //sampler2D texture = textures[textureIndex]; this is not allowed :/

    if (int(floor(vTextureIdx)) == 0) {
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(textures[0], vUv);
    } else {
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(textures[1], vUv);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Remember, GLSL is C-like, and C arrays cannot be dynamically allocated like that. Are you planning on adding/removing textures after a material is initialized? You could dynamically create the shader code, such that your number of textures is injected into your code.

Comment: @TheJim01 Ah now that's thinking outside the box. I love it. Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GLSL is a C-like language, and C arrays cannot be allocated using a variable for the size.

Instead, you can dynamically generate your shader code strings to have your number of textures integrated into the code. In your case, you'll want to do some replacement. As a minimal example:

```js
  var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({  
    uniforms: {

      verticesPerTexture: new Float32Array([4.0]), // store the count of vertices per texture

      cat_texture: {
        type: 't',
        value: loader.load(catUrl),
      },

      dog_texture: {
        type: 't',
        value: loader.load(dogUrl),
      },

      textures: {
        type: 'tv', // type for texture array
        value: textureArr,
      }
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent.replace(/!!!_TEXCOUNT_!!!/g,textureArr.length.toString());
  });
```

```html
<script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragment-shader'>
  precision highp float; // set float precision (optional)

  varying vec2 vUv; // identify the uv values as a varying attribute
  varying float vTextureIdx; // identify the texture indices as a varying attribute

  // you don't need cat_texture and dog_texture because they're in the following array
  uniform sampler2D textures[!!!_TEXCOUNT_!!!];

  void main() {
    int textureIndex = int(floor(vTextureIdx));

    if (int(floor(vTextureIdx)) == 0) {
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(textures[0], vUv);
    } else {
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(textures[1], vUv);
    }
  }
</script>
```

The replacement looks for the key `!!!_TEXCOUNT_!!!` and replaces it with the actual number of textures in your array.

Notice I also removed the `texture_num` uniform completely, because it's not longer needed. I also removed `cat_texture` and `dog_texture` because your textures are now held in the `textures` array.